# What type of mics for recording foley?

Tags: foley

I want to record some effects which aren't that sharp and I need to turn my preamp volume up and it leads to a lot of noises . Is there a special mic or a way to get rid of the noise?

Comment: good mic, good preamps. You get what you pay for. I'd say a DPA 4006 & at least something by a company that makes 'pro' gear rather than home. …but this is likely to be closed as too broad or opinion-based before long, unless you edit & hone your question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like a John Hardy or Sound Devices Pre would be a good choice, Mics vary depending on what your trying to capture sometimes it calls for a LDC and other times a DPA or Sen 416 or MKH50 might be the right choice.

If the sound isn't going to be loud in the mix then I feel ok capturing it at a lower level.  There is no reason to crank up your pre and introduce electrical noise if your just going to be bringing the sound down in the mix.  I've recorded super light fabric and cloth passes that read pretty low on meters but drop into the mix at a great level.